# As well as, as a conjunction

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, verbs, subject-verb-agreement

> 1. I, as well as he, am a doctor.
> 2. I as well as he are doctors.

In example 1, the verb agrees with the first subject because of commas while in the example 2, verb agrees with both subjects because of the absence of commas. But we are taught that it makes no difference either commas are used or not, verb must always agree to the distant subject. Then in this way the 2nd sentence stands incorrect. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Both  verb forms are possible in 2. It all depends on whether "as well as" is considered to be a coordinator or a subordinator.

Comment: Let's not confuse grammar and style. A thing can be grammatical and be really, really awkward.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *I, as well as he/him, am a doctor.*
>
> [2] *I as well as he/him are doctors*.

Both [1] and [2] are possible.

In [1] "as well as" behaves like a subordinator. The 3rd person singular verb-form "am" indicates that the subject is singular: "am" agrees with "I", so that "as well as he/him" is treated as an adjunct.

In [2] "as well as" behaves like the coordinator "and". The verb-form "are" indicates that the subject noun phrase is plural: "I" and "he/him" form a coordination of two nouns. "As well as" in [2] is thus best analysed as a compound coordinator. Unlike in [1] "as well as" does not form a constituent.

Note that the commas in [1] have no bearing on the verb-form.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinating conjunctions like "and", "but" etc are for joining *independent* clauses. A comma is normally placed before a coordinating conjunction.

> Example: "He is a doctor, and I am a consultant".

"As well as" is considered to be a subordinating conjunction - one that joins a dependent clause to an independent one.

> Example: "I am a doctor as well as a journalist"

Your first example is fine because it does require a subordinating conjunction. The statement is between two *parenthetical commas*, and would not stand as an independent statement.

Your second example doesn't work because you are using the expression to group two independent things together. It should just be:

> He and I are doctors.